# Transferred my singleplayer world onto a multiplayer server hoster and lost my inventory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanted to host a multiplayer vanilla survival server on Aternos for a Discord I frequent. After opening the server, not only is my skin gone, but my inventory is, too! I'm not sure what happened here, so can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like *Offline mode*

To correct this, find "Online-mode" in server.properties and change it to true.

```
online-mode=true
```

Your inventory disappears due to how minecraft servers handle UUID's when not online.